# Bootstrap centered 100% width cover responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, containers, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have troubles using the container class of bootstrap because I need a responsive 100% width cover. If I use this class I get a small margin in the left and in the right. So I want to that margins goes.  How can I do it and still getting responsive?

Here is the container class:

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

IF I use the col-12 class who is 100% width, the image goes to one side when I resize and I need a centered image when I resize.

Here is the cover using the container class, you notice the right and left margin

[image]

This is the look if i use the col-12 class:

[image]

And this is what I need but without the margins. (Of course only when I'm at 100%)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: are you loading in bootstrap-responsive.css ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3 and now bootstrap-responsive.css it's integrated in bootstrap.css, i get responsive if i use the container class but with those margins that i don't want.

Comment: so you want that image to be 100% of the window width at all times?

Comment: No if i zoom out (75%,50%,25%) to resize like all the frame.

Comment: Ok post your html of the container div that has the image in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the 100% width changing this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    }
}
```

To this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    }
}
```

That's because 1280px is the resolution of my screen.

Comment: is there a way make it works no matter what is the resolution of the screen?  the bootstrap 2 can handle that with fluid.

Comment: This isn't a solution for anyone with a screen resolution other than 1280px.